# I can't seem to find what's causing errors with my for loops

Tags: java, graphics

I'm taking an introductory computer science class in java. I'm trying to write a graphics program that solves the problem of...

*"Design a class that represents a star with a specified radius and color. Use a filled polygon to draw the star. Design and implement a program that draws 10 stars of random radius in random locations."*

So I finished what I thought would be fairly straightforward code, though when I go to compile the program I am getting 48 errors. The compiler seems to be complaining about almost every line of the program.

Any help with resolving these issues is greatly appreciated. (I hope it is a simple mistake that is affecting the majority of the program.)

Thanks in advance.

Here is a list of the errors (with file locations removed):

```
48 errors found:
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: ')' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 15]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 16]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 17]
Error: ']' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 17]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 17]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 17]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 17]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: ']' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 18]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: ']' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: <identifier> expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: illegal start of type
File: C...Star.java  [line: 19]
Error: ';' expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 22]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 25]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 28]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 29]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 31]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 31]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 31]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 34]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 35]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 36]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 37]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 47]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 50]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 52]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 52]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 52]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 55]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
File: C...Star.java  [line: 56]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Star Class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Star extends JPanel
{
  Random random = new Random();

  int radius = random.nextInt(10)+1;

  int[] xPos = new int[10];
  int[] yPos = new int[10];
  int[] rad = new int[10];

  for(int i=0; i!=10; i++)
  {
    int xPos[i] = random.nextInt(200)+1;
    int yPos[i] = random.nextInt(200)+1;
    int rad[i] = random.nextInt(10)+1;
  }

  public Star()
   {
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
   }

  int[] xStar = new int[10];
  int[] yStar = new int[10];
  int[] rad = new int[10];

  for(int ii=0; ii!=10; ii++)
  {
    private int[] (xStar[ii]) = {1*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 7*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii] };
    private int[] (yStar[ii]) = {5*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 4*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 1*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii] };
    private int[] (xStar2[ii]) = {1*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 7*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii] };
    private int[] (yStar2[ii]) = {5*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 6*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 9*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 7*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 7*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ yPos[ii] };
  }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up the basic characteristics of this panel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws a Star using polygons and polylines.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------

   public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
   {
      super.paintComponent(page);
      page.setColor(Color.red);

      for(int iii=0; iii!=10; iii++)
      {
        page.fillPolygon(yStar[iii], xStar[iii], xStar[iii].length);
        page.fillPolygon(yStar2[iii], xStar2[iii], xStar2[iii].length);
      }

   }
}
```

Star Painter (runner):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class StarClassCrushingMyDreams
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates the main frame of the program.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rocket");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(300,300);


      Star panel = new Star();



      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the `for` loops not being in initializer blocks or constructors (as in @John3136's answer), the contents of the loops are not valid:

```
int xPos[i] = random.nextInt(200)+1;
```

should be

```
xPos[i] = random.nextInt(200)+1;
```

You aren't declaring a variable, you are just assigning a value to an existing array.

Similarly:

```
private int[] (xStar[ii]) = {1*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 3*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 7*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii], 5*rad[ii]+ xPos[ii] };
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to write here. Certainly the `private int[]` shouldn't be there, but also `xStar` has type `int[]`, not `int[][]`.

Also, you haven't declared `xStar2` or `yStar2` anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You've got your for loops sitting out in the scope of the class, not inside a method. That isn't legal.

And you declare xPos etc in the scope of the for loop, so you won't actually be setting the class variables, just the shadow copies in the for loop.

Since I'm here: Having each star a a JPanel seems "odd", wouldn't you want to draw 10 stars in the same panel?